# Cannot clone Git repos. ~/.ssh/id_rsa verified in git

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, ssh

So I recently had to reinstall my OS which meant ssh-keygen. After logging into git it shows my new key as authenticated, but I am unable to clone anything.

Facts:
I am using Elementary OS which is a flavor of Ubuntu. 
I can successfully `git init` and create new branches recognized in my git admin/settings

Step 1.

```
sudo git clone git@github.com:angular/angular.js.git

:/opt/lampp/htdocs/Angles$ sudo git clone git@github.com:angular/angular.js.git
Cloning into 'angular.js'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Step 2.

```
ssh -T git@github.com
Hi USERNAME! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Step 3. (Trying authentication)

```
      m@Fido-desktop:/opt/lampp/htdocs/Angles$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" 
           Agent pid 8924 
      m@Fido-desktop:/opt/lampp/htdocs/Angles$ sudo ssh-add -l 
          Could not open a connection to your authentication agent. 
      m@Fido-desktop:/opt/lampp/htdocs/Angles$ ssh-add -l 
          The agent has no identities.
      m@Fido-desktop:/opt/lampp/htdocs/Angles$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
          Agent pid 9081 
      m@Fido-desktop:/opt/lampp/htdocs/Angles$ ssh-add-l 
          The agent has no identities.
```

Step 4. (Ubuntu Solutions?)

```
m@Fido-desktop:/opt/lampp/htdocs/Angles$ ssh -T git@github.com
     Hi USERNAME! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
m@Fido-desktop:/opt/lampp/htdocs/Angles$ eval 'ssh-agent -s'
     SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-kehosjF10336/agent.10336; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
     SSH_AGENT_PID=10337; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
     echo Agent pid 10337;
m@Fido-desktop:/opt/lampp/htdocs/Angles$ ssh-add -l
     2048 MY:SE:CU:RE:KE:Y0 /home/m/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
m@Fido-desktop:/opt/lampp/htdocs/Angles$ sudo git clone git@github.com:angular/angular.js.git
    [sudo] password for m: 
    Cloning into 'angular.js'...
    Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
m@Fido-desktop:/opt/lampp/htdocs/Angles$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo git clone` won't use the sames keys as `ssh -T git@github.com`.

- the former will look for keys in `/root/.ssh`
- the latter will look for keys in `/home/myAccount/.ssh`

Simply don't use `sudo` to clone.

Comment: Thank you so much. This solution worked for me. I am happy that the solution was so simple and kind of embarrassed at the same time. Thanks again.

Comment: @woodfordreserve no problem. I used to do the same mistake back in the day.